# Destiny disk deeply scratched - can I fix the disk or otherwise recover my progress?

Tags: xbox-360, destiny

I purchased Destiny along with map packs. I have made it to level 40 and my light-level is at 300. Unfortunately, my Xbox 360 overheated and caused the disc to have a deep dime sized burn.

Is there any solution to fixing the disc or do I have to repurchase and start all over again?

Comment: Isn't the game data stored in the Xbox hard drive, not the disk?

Answer (score 6):

The beauty of modern game systems (and many, many other applications) is that your saved games **do not depend** on the CD-ROM (which stands for 'Compact Disc - *Read Only* Memory') for storage. *Read only* means that the Xbox 360 only reads from the disc, and does not write to it. The memory is in the Xbox's hard drive, which means that your Destiny save data is dependent on the Xbox, not the Destiny game disc. Granted, it will probably be another $15 to buy another Destiny disc (available on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002I096Q4)), but you will not have to start all over from the beginning.

If you need more reassurance, please refer to this question, which explains you concern in greater detail: [Skyrim disc damaged, if I buy another will I still be able to play my saved games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96344/skyrim-disc-damaged-if-i-buy-another-will-i-still-be-able-to-play-my-saved-game)

Comment: Also, if the game was installed on the console, it may still be able to recognize the disc, and therefore play the game.

Comment: Can you expand on whether purchasing a digital copy of Destiny would work with the old disk-based save game?